# Anyone can help me inserting a background image in this code

Tags: html, css

```
#slide-1 .bcg {background-image:url('fancaps.jpg')}
```

I have the image fancaps.jpg in the same folder as my css and index file but when I preview it nothing happens. Anyone have any advice

Comment: Try '..\fancaps.jpg' or `#slide-1+.bcg{background-image:url('fancaps.jpg')}`

Comment: doesn't work. I followed this tutorial if this helps https://ihatetomatoes.net/how-to-create-a-parallax-scrolling-website/

Comment: inspect the background-image in slide-1 in your browser

Comment: Depends what you mean by 'nothing happen's but I would check the URL path. Currently your CSS is saying that fancaps.jpg can be found in the same file directory as the CSS file.

Comment: Can you show us the full code (html, css and jquery)?

Answer (score 0):

Change your CSS code to

```
 #slide-1 .bcg {
                background-image:url(fancaps.jpg); 
               }
```

OR

```
 #slide-1 .bcg {
                background:url(fancaps.jpg); 
               }
```

Tried both, either should work. If your images are in an "images" folder, adjust the folder with -

```
url(../images/imagename.jpg)
```